# PyBBM in Django static content

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get PyBBM 0.15.5 working on Django 1.6.3. Seems easy enough, but I run into a silly small problem which I don't know where to look for.

When PyBBM is trying to load static content, it does not use the correct URL. It uses:

> /forum/forum/2/topic/add/pybb/emoticons/shok.png

**^(fails)**

Instead of:

> /static/pybb/emoticons/shok.png

**^(works)**

Clearly something that generates the URL's based on some variable is not set correctly, but I dont know where to look. The PyBBM app? generic settings?

In my settings for my project, I have a static url setup as follows:

> STATIC_URL = '/static/'

The actual static content is in this directory:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybb/static/pybb/

Any hints are appreciated and forgive me my ignorance, as I am a novice coder.

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following context processor:

```
'django.core.context_processors.static',
```

After adding these, the STATIC_URL in settings.py was picked up correctly.
However I did also run into another issue, where PyBBM tested for a LANGUAGE_CODE in the context, which was not there. I solved this by adding this context processor:

```
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
```